# How do I create an object type that should have all the keys of an array type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic class to define a resource which has crud operations. My end goal is to have a generic class instance that can be used to create **services**, **reducer slices** and  **components** to automatically display data, filter and paginate a particular resource.
For the current use case this is what I want to define

> Resource City has parents state and country
> CityInstance.getPath should accept **ids** for **state** and **country** and return ***/country/1/states/1/cities***

```
export default class Resource {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  parents: string[];

  constructor(arg: { name: string; path: string; parents: string[] }) {
    this.name = arg.name;
    this.path = arg.path;
    this.parents = arg.parents;
  }
//I want the argument parentIds to include every single element of parents and their ids
  getBaseUrl(parentIds: {[parentName:string]=> id}){
       const parentPath = this.parents.map(p=>`/${p}/${parentIds[p]}`).join("");

       return `${parentPath}/${this.path}`
  }

}


const resource = new Resource({name:"city", parents: ["countries", "states"]})
//The next call should force me to supply the object of ids  and should not allow calls without them such as this one

resource.getBaseUrl({}) // Typescript should not allow


resource.getBaseUrl({country: 1}) // Typescript should not allow. 


//This would be valid since it supplies both state and country

resource.getBaseUrl({country: 1, state:2});
```

I realize that typescript cannot predict what the runtime values would be and therefore cannot infer types from the code alone. I have tried creating parents as a type but don't know how to work with that

```
class Resource<ResourceType,  Parents extends string[] =[] > {
    name:string
    resourceUrlName:string
    
    constructor(name:string,resourceUrlName:string){
        this.name=name
        this.resourceUrlName = resourceUrlName
    }
    //How do I specify that the indexer should be a part of parents array type
    generateBasePathForCollection(parents: {[name: keyof Parents} : number}){
      // How do I get all the members of the Parents Array

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do mapped types with the *values* of an array. What about changing the signature a little bit to help you? You *can* do a mapped type of object keys.

```
type WithParents<T extends Record<string, number>> = {
  baseUrl?: string;
  name: string;
  parents: T;
};

class Resource<T extends Record<string, number>> {
  baseUrl?: string;
  name: string;
  parents: T;

  constructor(args: WithParents<T>) {
    this.baseUrl = args.baseUrl;
    this.name = args.name;
    this.parents = args.parents;
  }

  getBaseUrl(input: { [P in keyof T]: string | number }) {
    const parts = Object.keys(this.parents).sort(k => this.parents[k]);
    return [this.baseUrl, ...parts.map(key => `${key}/${input[key]}`)]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join("/");
  }
}
```

The important parts here are the generics on the class and the `WithParents` type, and the mapped type arg (based on the generic argument on the class) in `getBaseUrl`. Here are the docs on mapped types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types

Then

```
const x = new Resource({ name: "string", parents: { countries: 1, state: 2 } });

console.log(x.getBaseUrl({ countries: 1, state: 2 })); // countries/1/state/2 
console.log(x.getBaseUrl({ state: 1, countries: 2 })); // countries/2/state/1 

const y = new Resource({ name: "string", parents: { state: 1, countries: 2 } });

console.log(y.getBaseUrl({ countries: 1, state: 2 })); // state/2/countries/1 
console.log(y.getBaseUrl({ state: 1, countries: 2 })); // state/1/countries/2
```

You could make it useful, like `{ countries: "number" }` and then do some validation on that while you're in there. As it stands, you can put *any* value for the value of the entry in the record and it'll work.

**Edit:** updated to maintain an ordering. Since the initial values for `parents` aren't used, we'll use their value to signify an order (starting from 1).

Comment: Right, arrays don't have keys. An array only has values that may be statically typed, but not for dynamic values.

Comment: The only problem is that the order of the parents matters. This could produce countries/1/state/1/cities or state/1/countries/2/cities

Comment: I am going to test this out and get back to you. I did think of using record but thought the ordering might be a problem

Comment: This is actually quite the novel solution and yes it does appear to work. https://repl.it/@slaith/DismalRaggedProcess#index.ts

I think the problem is the reliance on the order of stuff. Perhaps there's a way to remove that

Comment: Avoid using `any` as it should only be either `number` or `string` in an URL, or something that implements `toString(): string` or `valueOf(): number`.

Comment: I've updated to maintain order. Here's the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-butterfly-9j8xp. @TimTimWong sure... updated.

Comment: The original question append path at the end, but you prepend baseUrl in the beginning. Did I miss something?

Comment: @TimTimWong no.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to keep `parents`

`parents` is provided as an object of the same type of `parentIds` as `T`. The values of `parents` do not matter except their types. The order of the keys is preserved.

```js
export default class Resource<T extends { [parentName: string]: number }> {
    name: string;
    path: string;
    parents: T;

    constructor({ name, path, parents }: { name: string; path: string; parents: T; }) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.parents = parents;
    }
    // You want the argument parentIds to include every single element of parents and their ids
    getBaseUrl(parentIds: T) {
        const parentPath = Object.keys(this.parents).map(p => `/${p}/${parentIds[p]}`).join("");

        return `${parentPath}/${this.path}`
    }

}


const resource = new Resource({ name: "city", path: "dont-forget-path", parents: { country: 0, state: 0 } })
//The next call should force me to supply the object of ids  and should not allow calls without them such as this one

resource.getBaseUrl({}) // Typescript should not allow


resource.getBaseUrl({ country: 1 }) // Typescript should not allow. 


//This would be valid since it supplies both state and country

resource.getBaseUrl({ country: 1, state: 2 });
```

Note that `{[parentName:string]=> id}` is invalid as `=>` should be `:` and `id` must be a type instead.

Moreover, don't forget to put `path` when calling the constructor.

Comment: The only problem is that the order of the parents matters. This could produce countries/1/state/1/cities or state/1/countries/2/cities